# Bulk uploads in XML Form libray

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, xml, forms-library, excel-import

I would like to know how can I import 500 records (in an Excel file) to XML form library in SharePoint Online.

This XML form library was created with InfoPath 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The form library is a library, we only can upload the files in the form library. We cannot import the records from the excel to the form library.

Then if you want to import the records from excel to SharePoint online, you could go to site contents->create a app “Import Spreadsheet”.

More reference:

[3 ways to import Excel to SharePoint.](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-import-excel-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case, I would need to find out how to convert the Excel files to XML where each row in Excel is a XML entry in the form library.